# logistic regression assigning low probability score to actual 1 in dataset

Tags: r, classification, logistic

I did logistic regression in r having 35,000 rows and 284 variables in dataset. After removing alias variables, vif and backward selection 25 variables remained on which logistic regression was performed using glm function of which 15 came significant. Dependent variable is binary( 1's & 0's) of which 30% is 1.

The challenge is model assigning very low probability score to actual 1's in data set. The score for both 1's and 0's are almost overlapping.

Ideally high score should be given to actual 1's. What could be the reason? please suggest.

Comment: Most probably the predictors on the rhs of your equation aren't very good at predicting your dependent variable. You may want to use a package like caret as a wrapper for your model. Using cross validation add and remove variables from your model formulae to see how they improve/reduce the prediction. Try creating new variable from your existing predictor (called Feature Engineering). This is a useful resourse: http://will-stanton.com/machine-learning-with-r-an-irresponsibly-fast-tutorial/

Comment: What is the proportion of 1s and 0s in your target class?

Comment: @ Zach. actual 1's are 30% and rest 70% are 0's. If percentage of 1's are less in data set then model could give low score to actual 1's but here it is good 30%

Comment: Try to change the threshold: `ifelse(prob > 0.3, 1, 0)`

Comment: @ fernando. with low threshold FP s increases drastically bringing down specificity. model classifies more of o's as 1